# Setting permissions in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I need some of my users to see/update only the boards others to see Repos, others to see the Pipelines only. Is there a way to set such permissions?

I couldn't find any default permission that does this

Comment: fairly certain there are default permissions for that. but you'd need to not include people into default groups, as they give to much permissions for your usecase

Answer (score 1):

The lowest access level we can give is stakeholder and set users as Project Reader, this makes Repos invisible at most.Users can still see Boards and Pipelines,but without permission to update.

If you don't want some users to see Repos, then you can set the access level of these users to **Stakeholder**, and then check the project in **Manage projects** that you want the user to enter, so that these users can only see Boards and Pipelines without Repos in the project. **Note**:Make sure that the project you want these users to enter is a private project.
[image][image]

You can also set up the following settings to make the content in Repos inaccessible.

Setting: Project Settings -> Repos Repositories ->select the users or groups which you want to set permission -> change the **Read** permission to **Deny**
[image]

In addition you can make the build pipeline and release pipeline in the Pipelines service invisible to the specified users.

Settings: Pipelines Builds -> Click "⋮" choose **Security** -> select the users or groups you want to set permissions -> Change the **View build pipeline** permission to **Deny**

The same setting in Releases can make the release pipeline invisible.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This should answer what I am looking for. I will test and see.

Comment: What is the result of your test?